# cargar datos automáticamente desde excel a sql server

Tags: sql, .net, excel

Tengo un formulario web en .Net desde el cual el usuario carga archivos de Excel  para hacer un cruce de informacion con los registros de la base de datos Sql server, esto se hace en caliente (el usuario sube el archivo y genera el cruce de informacion en el mismo instante).

pregunta: Existe alguna forma de procesar esos archivos de Excel en un tiempo posterior , es decir que el usuario suba todos los archivos de excel que quiera en el día y en la noche (cuando la base de datos es menos utilizada) genere ese cruce de informacion.

Comment: Sí existe. Sólo tienes que usar el agente de SQL Server y generar un job. O puedes conseguir una herramienta de control de flujo como _Control M_, o hasta las tareas programadas de Windows. La pregunta es muy amplia y más si no sabemos exactamente a que te refieres con "cruce de información" (una consulta, importación de datos, creación de nuevos datos, etc).

Comment: Consulta de informacion (cruce=comparacion entre los datos que lleva el excel y lo que se encuentra en la base de datos).

Comment: Y que haces con esa comparación? Cómo realizas esa comparación? Con T-SQL? SSIS? OPENROWSET? .NET?